# Uploading file to server using POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, post

Trying this API: https://www.newocr.com/api/

I need to translate this:

```
curl -H "Expect:" -F file=@./path/to/file http://api.newocr.com/v1/upload?key=api_key
```

Into javascript, given a png image file base64 object.

This didn't work (404):

```
function upload(image) {
  var url = 'http://api.newocr.com/v1/upload?key=' + api_key;
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', image);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', url);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
  request.send(formData);
}
```

Comment: Looking in the JS console, I see something that appears to make sense - that it needs a CORS header. So I try adding one and the same result. Digging a little deeper, I go to look at the request headers. During this time, I notice that the METHOD for my request is listed as OPTIONS - not the POST that I was expecting. I suspect this is why we're getting a 404 and not a 400. I might try with some native socket code later to see how much the browser is helping/hindering the process.

Comment: I should add - when trying to do this with a form and no ajax, it succeeds - that is, I get a json response that includes the status and the id of the file I just uploaded.